# Could not find SpecFlow Feature Files option in Add New Item window - VS20019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am new to visual studio and specflow. I have visual studio 2019 in my machine and I have followed all steps and successfully installed specflow through manage nuget package .
 I cannot add a feature file from right click on proj> Add new item. I cannot see specflow .
 Can anyone help me on how to add feature files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you also installed the Visual Studio Extension for SpecFlow? I think that is what provides the feature file listing in Add New Item.

To install go to Tools > Extensions and Updates > Online then search for Specflow:

[image]

Note in my screenshot it is already installed but there should be a download button when you hightlight specflow in the list like e.g.

[image]

Once you've clicked Download and marked it for install close Visual Studio, let it install, and then try again - you should then see the templates.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I use VS 2019 edition I installed Specflow in solution level and still I could not see the SpecFlow Category

Answer (score 3):

I have installed through extensions->visual studio marketplace and downloaded .
Attached the screenshot.
[image]
Still I cannot add a feature file from right click on proj> Add new item.

Comment: Have you solved this? same scenario here!

Comment: I solved here, in my case was the type of the project, At the top of my cs proj file was referecing Microsoft.NET.Sdk. In the web project you cannot add feature files

Answer (score 1):

Please perform below steps:

1. Click on Extensions -> Manage Extensions

[image]

2. Click on 'Online' and enter specflow in search box

[image]

3. Click on Download button
4. Restart the Visual Studio (this step is **mandatory** to install the Extensions after downloading)
5. After successful installation you can see the Specflow options

[image]